# Error Undefined

Tags: php, html

Este es el error que me aparece

> Notice: Undefined index: folio in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Kenworth\www\prestamos.php on line 82

y estes el es código

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])||isset($_POST['folio'])||isset($_POST['nombre'])||!isset($_POST['entrega'])||!isset($_POST['devolucion'])||!isset($_POST['concepto'])||!isset($_POST['cantidad'])||!isset($_POST['descripcion'])||!isset($_POST['solicita'])||!isset($_POST['autoriza'])){
  $folio = $_POST['folio'];
```

Comment: `if( isset( $_POST['folio'] ) ) $folio = $_POST['folio'];`

Comment: Algunas de las demás condiciones se cumple y entra en el `if`.

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);`? ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente con todos esos `if`... propondría un código más limpio y ordenado, evaluando y guardando los datos en variables con un operador ternario, y luego usar esas variables para todo lo que haga falta hacer con ellas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, prueba así:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['folio'])){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])||isset($_POST['folio'])
        ||isset($_POST['nombre'])||!isset($_POST['entrega'])
        ||!isset($_POST['devolucion'])||!isset($_POST['concepto'])
        ||!isset($_POST['cantidad'])||!isset($_POST['descripcion'])
        ||!isset($_POST['solicita'])||!isset($_POST['autoriza'])
    ){
        $folio = $_POST['folio'];
    }
} else $folio=null; 
?>
```

Lo único que hago es asegurarme de que `$_POST['folio']` exista

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)